# Why there is an extra tiny hole on the car wheels

Tags: wheels

What is the purpose of this hole on car wheels?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Many cars have hubs with a locating pin for the wheel to help in mounting.

That hole is to match the pin.

Answer (score 1):

They used to balance wheels on the car, so that the wheel and the hub were balanced together.

The hole is so that if the wheel is removed, it will be replaced in the same orientation to the hub (if there is a matching pin).